# Where is Virtualbox adapter

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vmware, interface

Before when I had Windows 7 and installed VMware. When I want to make a LAN connection between my host (my *Windows 7* ) and guest (Any OS suppose *Windows XP*). I set connection to `NAT`. After that I can ping my Windows XP from Window 7 and Vice versa.

Also there were an interface adapter in my Windows 7 which I can change its IP. So where is this network adapter or is there any? when I type `ifconfig` I do not see anything related to virtual network.

Comment: try `ifconfig -a` for see all

Comment: I try that just eth0 , lo and wlan0

Comment: I think this should be close as nothing to deal with Ubuntu. Only with an edit that show it relation to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `ifconfig -a` to see all interfaces

If nothing there, you may add new one:

1. Open VirtualBox
2. From menu: File → Preferences...
3. Network → Host-only Networks
4. Click (+) to insert new one

[image: vboxnet host-only adapter]